# While loop not running if statements right

Tags: php, mysql

So I have have a while loop and it does work in terms of the database and if statements etc.. however for some reason the if statements are not running correctly

Here is the code (edited)

```
<?php session_start( ); ?>
<?php include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/header.php';

require 'core/database/db_connection.php';

function friend_check($user_id, $friend_id) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fyp_friends WHERE user_id={$user_id} AND         friend_id={$friend_id} AND type=1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num_rows;
}

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/members.css">
<?php
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     --------------------*/
  //Get user information from fyp_users
  $sql = ("SELECT user_id, user_name, first_name, last_name, email, profile FROM     fyp_users");
 $user =mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 //$userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($user);
 //echo $userinfo['user_id'];

//Get friend information from fyp_users
//$sql = ("SELECT user_id, friend_id, type FROM fyp_friends");
//$friend =mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
//$friendinfo = mysql_fetch_array($friend);
//echo $friendinfo['user_id'];
?>

<?php
while ($usermain = mysql_fetch_array($user)) {

echo '<div id="friends">';
echo '<div class="profilepiclarge"><img src="', $usermain['profile'], '"alt="',    $usermain['first_name'],'\'s Profile Image"></div>';
?>
<div class="userinfo">
<?php 
echo "</br>{$usermain['first_name']}";
echo "</br>{$usermain['last_name']}";
echo "</br>{$usermain['email']}";
echo "</br>{$usermain['user_name']}</br>";
echo '<div class="viewprofile">';
echo "<a href='profile.php?user_name={$usermain['user_name']}'>View Profile</a>";
echo '</div>';

$sql = ("SELECT user_id, friend_id, type FROM fyp_friends WHERE user_id=       {$usermain['user_id']}");
$friend =mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$friend_result = friend_check($session_user_id, $usermain['user_id']);
echo $friend_result;
if ($usermain['user_id'] === $session_user_id) {
echo "This is you"; 
} else if (intval($friend_result) == 1) {
echo '<div class="removefriend">';
    echo"Remove Friend";
    echo '</div>';
} else if (intval($friend_result) == 0) {
echo '<div class="addfriend">';
    echo"Add Friend";
    echo '</div>';
}

echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

//If statment to go here to see if already friends dont show add friends function also if     current user is logged in sont show it. If already friends the option 
//to remove the user as a fried becomes avalible

}
```

Comment: How many records are there in `fyp_friends`?

Comment: Are you sure `fyp_friends` doesn't contain duplicate rows? Try using a SQL browser and check the results against what you're expecting.

Comment: putvande currently just 3. Michael Todd and yeah already check that and there are no duplicates.

Comment: your `fyp_friends` query is being called every row which i cannot see a reason for you have no WHERE clause so the rows found will always be the same =/ Why is it in the loop at all ?

Comment: I have tried it with out been a loop and it only out puts the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query has no WHERE clause so i'm not seeing how you are listing friends related to the user in question, change the query to :

```
SELECT user_id, friend_id, type FROM fyp_friends WHERE user_id = $usermain['user_id']
```

Comment: Try changing the loops and use `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Nahh, not happening that stopping the looping of the second while all together.